# Change kafka topic retention from infinite to finite

Tags: apache-kafka

I have kafka topic configured with `cleanup.policy=compact` and `retention.ms=-1` - so infinite retention.

What I want to do is change it, I want the events to be compacted time to time. When I create new topic with following configuration it works fine:

```
cleanup.policy=compact
config retention.ms=5000
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0
segment.ms=1000
```

When I produce events to such topic it is compacted as expected.

Problem is when I have topic with retention set to infinite (-1), and change it's config by `kafka-configs --alter`. Using `kafka-topics --describe` I can verify that the changes were successful, but the topic is not compacted. How can I "trigger" those config changes? I also tried restarting the broker and zookeeper, but it didn't do the trick.

I'm using kafka 2.7.0

Comment: Compaction isn't immediate and is ran on a background thread that cannot just be triggered. Also, this isn't changing anything to "finite" retention since you've not changed the cleanup policy

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm aware that compaction is not immediate. However the time is set to 5 seconds, so I expect it should run after a few minutes. It works in case of new topic, why doesn't it work when I change the config of old topic?

The cleanup policy is "compact" in both cases and it works in one case but doesn't in the other.

Comment: Sometimes the log cleaner thread dies. At least, it's a bug that's been reported in the past. Otherwise, the cleaner only works on closed segments

Comment: Without knowing your exact data, it'll be difficult to give you a direct answer, but this blog goes over an investigative deep dive into compaction settings https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/an-investigation-into-kafka-log-compaction-5e520f4291f0

Comment: My test data are simple messages: key is random integer in 0-5 range (so it repeats often to test compaction), value is timestamp.

Comment: `log.segment.bytes` defaults to 1GB. Are you actually sending more than 1GB of data? If not, then there will be no closed segments in the "tail" of the log

Comment: I have `segment.ms` set to 1000, and according to documentation: "This configuration controls the period of time after which Kafka will force the log to roll even if the segment file isn't full to ensure that retention can delete or compact old data."

Comment: I cannot remember which takes precedence. When you dump the log segments, is there only 1second worth of data in each file? Or are they several MB to 1GB large?

Comment: I have `segment.bytes` set to 128 which is definitely smaller than size of my messages.

Comment: I created the topic with compaction, low retention (like 5 seconds), low segment sizes (like 128 bytes) etc. It worked - the log was compacted. I altered config to infinite retention - it worked. I altered it back to small retention, sizes etc - it doesn't work. No compaction any more.

Comment: I don't have a definite answer. If you think it's a bug, file a JIRA. I will point out that the log cleaner has a limited number of threads and your OS has a limited number of open file handles. Therefore, only so many log segments can be opened and dirty ratios calculated per log cleaner interval. Obviously generating up to 60 or more segments per minute isn't a good idea